# Apply class conditionally to component host

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to apply a class to the component tag only if something is true.

How I could turn this host into a conditional host so that I will apply the desired class when needed?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'k-sidebar',
  host: {
   class: '{{isChanged}}'
 },
 templateUrl: './ng-k-side-bar.component.html',
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the host element class conditionally with `@HostBinding`:

```
condition: boolean = true;

@HostBinding("class") private get hostClass(): string {
  return this.condition ? "redBorder" : "";
}
```

or for a specific class name (e.g. `redBorder`):

```
@HostBinding("class.redBorder") private get hasRedBorder(): boolean {
  return this.condition;
}
```

See these two demos: [stackblitz 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scfmha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), [stackblitz 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atg3va?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks! this actually makes totally sense!

Answer (score 2):

if 'my-class' is a class name you setup it like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'k-sidebar',
  host: {
   '[class.my-class]': 'isChanged'
 },
 templateUrl: './ng-k-side-bar.component.html',
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyComponent {
  isChanged = true;
}
```